# How to get a title at the top of a cover letter?

Tags: resume, newlfm

I am using the `newlfm` package to create a cover letter. And I am trying to replace the logo at the top of this cover letter with a title. Now I know how to remove the logo, but I have no idea how to add a title above the black line at the top ? 
Plus, I cannot find any latex code that created those 2 black lines in the image, and thats why I dont know how to place a title or some text just right above the upper black line

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} % Extra options: 'sigleft' for a left-aligned signature, 'stdletternofrom' to remove the from address, 'letterpaper' for US letter paper - consult the newlfm class manual for more options

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

\lthUiuc % Print the company/institution logo

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namefrom{John Smith} % Name

\addrfrom{
\today\\[12pt] % Date
123 Broadway \\ % Address
City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

\emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} % Closing text

\nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith} % Addressee of the letter above the to address

\addrto{
Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
The Corporation \\
123 Pleasant Lane \\
City, State 12345
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e. career development center, newspaper, employment service, personal contact).
```

[image]

Comment: Your MWE is missing 2 lines at the end: `\end{newlfm}` and
`\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the `\includegraphics` with you title, being sure to match the `{` & `}`s.  In other words, change 3 lines to:

```
\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
This is a dummy title }}
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}
```

And you will have "This is a dummy title" above the line (which, by the way, is added by the package, hence why you can't see the command to draw it).

You can use any text formatting commands you like in the title, to change the size for example, just as in body text.